# How to use round rect cube on Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my program i want to ordering a cube one by one.

I am using normal cube object. In my program, initially contains one cube positioning on center of the screen, another one cube is oscillated horizontally on top. when touch the screen that cube is fall down on that ground cube. again another cube is oscillated. When I hit the screen, oscillated cube is fall down on that previous cube. Vice versa I am ordering cube one by one.

Now my problem is, when oscillate cube is holding on previous cube edge part, that oscillate cube want to fall down the ground. In my program I am using asusual cube game object so when one cube touch on another cube edge side that cube hold on that cube instead of force down on ground.